# IT IS football boots vs THEY ARE football boots

Tags: pronouns

In my textbook I have seen:

> they are football boots

question:
it is interchangeable with:

> it is football boots ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not interchangable.

"Boots" is plural. In a simple "It is X" sentence the pronoun "It" or "They" refers to the complement (X).  If the complement is plural, you need a plural pronoun too.  And so the verb must have plural form

> They are football boots.

Or use the "a pair of" structure:

> It's a pair of football boots.

---

<sub>"It is" can be used with a plural, when "it" refers to something specifically singular. E.g.</sub>

> <sub>What is the greatest joy in life?</sub>
>
> <sub>It's the people you love.</sub>

<sub>In this case "it" refers to "the greatest joy", which is singular. The fact that the answer ("the people you love") is plural does not change the fact that "it" is singular.</sub>

Comment: This doesn't quite cover all use cases. "It is" can be used with a plural, when "it" refers to something specifically singular. E.g. "What is the greatest joy in life? / It's the people you love". In this case "it" refers to "the greatest joy", which is singular. The fact that the answer ("the people you love") is plural does not change the fact that "it" is singular.

Comment: I agree.  But for this answer I am trying to keep it simple. The example was a simple example and I think discussing the exceptions would be confusing.  Perhaps I'll incorporate your comment in a footnote.

Comment: Thanks guys! it is  enough answer for me.